# How to make Inline button in HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt" id="navlist">
<li style="list-style: none;">
    <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Home.html">
       <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Home">
    </FORM>
    <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Rooms.html">
        <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Rooms">
    </FORM>
    <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Contacts.html">
        <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Contacts">
    </FORM>
</ul>
```

I cant make them all at the same line or make them go in horizontal order any ideas?

Comment: That `<li>` isn't closed.

Comment: Do you need the submit action? It looks like you're just creating a navigation structure, which should be facilitated by normal links (`<a href="home.html">Home</a>`) and then styled accordingly

Comment: @helle you just changed the meaning of the question, you shouldn't do such radical edits, people just accept the reviews blindly

Comment: I don't think that anything else was ment ... he/she is a html rooky anyway ;)

Comment: still studying sorry :(

Comment: @helle No but we shouldn't fix the code, if you feel that's the issue you can feel free to answer... also the current markup is absolutely valid, he is just missing `li` tag

Comment: @user2882523 what is the reason that you use `FORM` tags which only hold a  submit-buttons? what are you goning to archive with that idea?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, li are displayed in block. You need to declare a specific CSS rule for the li:

```
li, form{
display:inline;
}
```

UPDATE:

As Mr.Alien said, review your HTML syntax first. Write something like :

```
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt" id="navlist">
    <li style="list-style: none;">
        <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Home.html">
           <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Home">
        </FORM>
</li>
<li style="list-style: none;">
        <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Rooms.html">
            <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Rooms">
        </FORM>
</li>
<li style="list-style: none;">
        <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Contacts.html">
            <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Contacts">
        </FORM>
</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: `form` needs `inline` and not `li`, also he is not closing `li`

Comment: i forgot to add the </li> so i should make the it like form{ display:inline;}?

Comment: @miam its still at vertical order though cant make it to horizontal

Answer (score 1):

Make the `<li>`'s and `<form>`'s display inline

```
ul {list-style-type: none;}
ul li {display:inline;}
ul li form {display:inline;}
```

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dM2hY/)